# Chrome v57 - errors after mouse move in grid

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

a long time we are developing one webapplication, that was running fine on Chrome 56. After Chrome upgrade on version 57.0.2987.* we are encountering a big problem. Sometimes if I'm moving with mouse, some errors will apears:

[image: mousemove error]

[image: VM5534]

[image: main.min.js]

when this erros will apears, we cannot click on some functions like this:

[image]

it will generate another error:

[image: another error]

so our application is in this state useless.

However, after refresh is all fine, after another refresh can this errors apears again. We don't know how to exactly simulate this bug.

**Did someone encounter any similar problem?**

PS: I'm not developer of this webapp, but if you need any other info, just ask. First I was asking [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/B74moRYxKE8;context-place=forum/chrome)

Edit: On chrome 56 it works, on beta chrome 58 it works too without these errors.

Comment: Ok, sorry then. I thought, that was you, because you edited it and -1 apears immedietely after that. And I was accidentaly deleted my previous comment, so sorry for that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just creepy version of Chrome. These errors was only on Chrome version 57. Other versions are ok. Even Google released version 58 faster, then it was expected.